# For which norm-Euclidean domains is the proof interval less than $1$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I saw a proof somewhere (can't find it at the moment) that shows $\textbf{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is norm-Euclidean because for any pair of nonzero numbers $a, b$ it's possible to find a remainder $r$ such that $$N(r) \leq \frac{3}{4} N(b).$$ In Bolker's error-prone book, a proof covering $\textbf{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, $\textbf{Z}[i]$, $\textbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ shows that in each of these domains it's always possible to find $$N(r) \leq \frac{1}{2} N(b).$$ Maybe I'm recalling incorrectly, because it seems to me that if $\frac{1}{2}$ does it for these four domains, then $\frac{3}{4}$ is too much for $\textbf{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. Basic logic suggests that at the most general level, $1$ is the absolute maximum, with strict inequality, of course.

Do any of the norm-Euclidean quadratic rings require $1$ for the proof interval?  Or is $\frac{1}{2}$ always sufficient? Or is there more variety than this?

Comment: Perhaps you're referring to https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~par31/notes/ed.pdf ? The penultimate line asserts $$N(r) \leq \frac{3}{4} N(c + d \sqrt{-2}).$$

Comment: Which are the **four domains**?

Comment: The Bolker book that *I* am looking at references $\textbf{A}(m)$ (an archaic notation for the ring of algebraic integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$) for $m = -2, -1$, 2 or 3, Theorem 33.4 on page 104.

Comment: As I think more about it, I think you've misread Bolker. My understanding is that the interval of proof is $$\frac{1}{4} + \frac{|d|}{4}$$ for $d = -2, -1,$ 2 or 3. For the remaining negative $d$ corresponding to norm-Euclidean domains, Bolker gives $$\frac{1}{4} + \frac{|d|}{16}$$ in Theorem 33.5, giving $$\frac{15}{16}, \frac{11}{16}, \frac{7}{16}$$ and for $d = 5$ or 13, $$\frac{5}{16}, \frac{13}{16}.$$

Comment: I apologize for all the errors. You can find a list at http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/numberTheory/ . I think @RobertSoupe 's comment confirms my argument. Of course that doesn't answer your more general question.

Comment: That reminds me, @Ethan, I have to travel back in time and make you make those mistakes. Without my meddling, your text would have had less than a page's worth of errata. I know, I know, it's one of those pesky predestination paradoxes.

Answer (score 4):

The infimum of all values of $c$ such that $f(r) \le c f(b)$ for all pairs of $r$ and $b$ is called the Euclidean minimum for the (Euclidean) function $f$. If $f$ is the absolute value of the norm, the classical name is 
"inhomogeneous minimum of the norm form".

If $f$ is the minimal Euclidean function on a domain as defined by Motzkin, then $c = 1$. If $f$ is the absolute value of the norm, then we must have $c < 1$ if the ring is norm-Euclidean, as was shown by Barnes and Swinnerton-Dyer in the quadratic and by Cerri in the case of general number fields.
If the ring contains a principal ideal of norm $a > 1$, then we always have $c > 1/a$. I do not know whether every rational value of $c > 0$ does occur
as a Euclidean minimum for the norm function.

For more information, see my [survey](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/survey.pdf).